# Running a task repeatedly with a variable interval

Tags: java, swing, timer

My program is pretty simple - it generates a random number and then increments an array at that index, essentially tallying how often it comes up, which is displayed in a bar graph type JPanel. It does this every "updateInterval" milliseconds, 50 by default. I'm trying to, upon user input, change this interval. My initial code was this:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
GenerateNumberTask genTask = new GenerateNumberTask(); //extends TimerTask

public void startTimer(){
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(genTask, 0, updateInterval); 
}
```

For obvious reasons, changing 'updateInterval' doesn't change the used interval once it has begun. I had thought that calling this next code afterwards in the needed area (the button ActionListener it's being changed from) would update the timer with the new interval, but it doesn't.

```
t.purge();
genTask = new GenerateNumberTask();
t.startTimer();
```

Afterwards, I looked into ScheduledExecutorService, but that just confused me more.

It seems like the next thing would be to make a new Thread(), run the task as a Runnable and just Thread.sleep the interval.

What's the correct way of going at this?

EDIT: At the suggestion of @MadProgrammer, I've changed it to a swing timer, yet the problem still stands.

```
public void startTimer(){
    t = new Timer(timeBetweenUpdates, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //irrelevant code 
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

later, in the actionlistener

```
//timeBetweenUpdates changes before this line
t.setDelay(timeBetweenUpdates);
```

Still, the result it the same.

**EDIT 2: Solved it. I accidentally called the startTimer() in both the constructor and main method.**

Comment: Use a Swing javax.swing.Timer instead so you not violate the thread rules of a Swing

Comment: I believe you have to cancel the task and reschedule it

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've changed my code, I'll add to the OP.

Comment: How are you getting input from the user?

Comment: Via a textField, then using parseInt to determine the value. Anyway, it works... sort of. It seems to be scheduling another concurrent instance of the same task, then only changing the second one (or maybe the first, I don't know which).

EDIT: ... nevermind. I was stupidly calling startTimer() in both the main method and my constructor. The error is fixed. Here's the full code - not sure why someone would want to see it, but here it is anyway. HintTextField is a modified JTextField I found on SO. [link](http://pastebin.com/C5mJaJ0j)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a Swing (`javax.swing`) `Timer`, this will set up a regular callback which is executed with the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, making it safe to update the UI from within.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TestTimer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTimer();
    }

    public TestTimer() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                TestPane testPane = new TestPane();
                Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        testPane.repaint();
                    }
                });
                JSlider slider = new JSlider(10, 1000);
                slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        timer.setDelay(slider.getValue());
                    }
                });
                slider.setValue(10);
                timer.start();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(testPane);
                frame.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private long lastUpdate = -1;

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            String text = "...";
            if (lastUpdate > 0) {
                long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdate;
                text = Long.toString(duration);
            }
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
            lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```